# iTerm2: is there a setting to favor new window rather than new tab when opening a new profile?

Tags: iterm2

Basically, I want every new profile opened to be in a new window (and I will use some window-management tools like Spectacle in macOS, to manage the windows). Currently, it opens in a tab inside one of the iTerm2 windows, and I have to drag it out to form its new window.

I thought there was a setting 7 years ago? Haven't been using iTerm2 until recently. Now I scanned through the settings and didn't find anything.

Tried a quick search and didn't find any existing question (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iterm2+open+profile+in+new+window+instead+of+new+tab), so asking here.